# Does root_vnode get garbage collected?

Tags: javascript

Does root_vnode get garbage collected?
E.g. If I create a 'game' object with that function and later on go to call the .root getter, does it still have reference to root_vnode?

```
export default function createGameAPI(tree){ 
    let game = {}

    // Get ref to root virtual node
    let root_node = tree.getRoot()
    let root_vnode = tree.VNCache.get(root_node.id, root_node)

    // Set 'root' property
    Object.defineProperty(game.prototype, 'root', {
        set: val => { return null },
        get: () => { return root_vnode }
    })

    return game
}
```

Comment: The anonymous arrow function that is assigned to `get` has a closure reference to it, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Does not get garbage collected, 2) does still have reference

Closures in javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures